# About the Laplace transform of the sine function

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $t > 0$ and $a$ is a constant. Show that $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx} \sin(ax) dx = \frac{a}{t^2 + a^2} $$

The hint was to use the exponential formula, and I get that

$\sin(ax) = \frac{e^{iax} - e^{-iax}}{2i}$

and I replace it within the integral to get:

$$I = \frac{1}{2i} \cdot \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx}(e^{iax} - e^{-iax}) dx$$

But I cannot go further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just integrate now, $\displaystyle\int e^{ax}\,dx = a^{-1}e^{ax}+C$, so apply this and get a common denominator to see

> $$\int_0^\infty {1\over 2i}\left({e^{ai-t}\over ai-t}+{e^{-ai-t}\over ai+t}\right|_0^\infty = {1\over 2i}\left({1\over ai-t}+{1\over ai+t}\right)$$
>   $$={a\over t^2+a^2}$$

Comment: Where do you get the  $$\frac{e^{ai - t}}{ai - t}$$ from?

Comment: @ayylmao read my first line, it's from the integration!

Comment: If I am following, you went from $$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{x(ai - t)}$$, but I don't se how you evaluate $$\frac{e^{(ai - t)x}}{ai - t}\bigg |_{0}^{\infty}$$ since it is a complex form

Comment: $|e^{ai-t}|=e^{-t}\stackrel{t\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$. Dividing by the $ai\pm t$ doesn't change that since you can triangle inequality the denominator. Pro-tip: don't try to prove a limit is $0$ in complex analysis, try and prove its absolute value is $0$.

Comment: The variable is **not** $t$, the variable with respect to is $x$. Thats where the issue for me was. I am not sure how to see what happens to $$e^{(ai - t)x}$$ as $x \to \infty$

Comment: @ayylmao oh right, same thing though, just replace $t$ with $tx$. Since $t>0$ $tx\to \infty\iff x\to\infty$.

Comment: Alright, was about $aix$?

Comment: @ayylmao $aix$ is an imaginary number you should know that $e$ to the imaginary power has absolute value $1$.

Comment: That is fine, but I am more concerned about evaluating the limit as $x$ tends to infinity, since how can a complex number evaluate to a real number?

Comment: @ayylmao it doesn't matter, the absolute value is $1$, so it doesn't change the overall limit. I think the part you're having trouble with is you think you have to evaluate all the pieces completely: that's not so, you just need that the whole limit goes to $0$, in fact $e^{aix}$ has **no** limit as $x\to\infty$, but $|e^{aix}|$ **does**, so it matters that you are able to take absolute values.

Comment: How does one evaluate a complex limit?

Comment: @ayylmao the same way you do a real one: given $\epsilon > 0 $ find $L\in\Bbb C$ so that when $|z-z_0|<\delta\implies |f(z) -L|< \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach. The sine function is a solution of the differential equation
$$ f''+f = 0 $$
and by applying a [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) to both sides we get
$$ (\mathcal{L}f)(s) + s^2 (\mathcal{L} f)(s) = f'(0)+s\,f(0) $$
so that
$$ (\mathcal{L} f)(s) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(x) e^{-sx}\,dx = \frac{1}{s^2+1} $$
and the claim follows from a straightforward substitution.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

It's simpler to use the $\mathrm e^{-tx}\sin ax=\operatorname{Im}\mathrm e^{(-t+ia)x}$. The antiderivative of this function (w.r.t. $x$) is
$$\frac1{-t+ia}e^{(-t+ia)x}=-\frac{t+ia}{t^2+a^2}\,e^{-tx}e^{iax},$$
and all you have to do is to finish extracting its imaginary part.

Comment: What about the evaluation from 0 to infinity?

Comment: That's left to you… It is only a hint.

Comment: BTW, it was $e^{-tx} \sin(aX)$ not $\sin(aT)$, capitalized to show you. Is that a problem?

Comment: Oh! Sorry. I misrread the integral. I'll fix it in a second.

Comment: Thanks. I am having trouble with $$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{(-t + ai)x} dx$$, can you give me a hint?

Comment: The problem is evaluation at the bounds?

Comment: Yes sir, that is the issue I am having since we also have an imaginary constant

Comment: I rewrote the antiderivative. Note that $\bigl\lvert\mathrm e^{iax}\bigr\rvert=1$, so the antiderivative tends to $0$ when $x$ tends to $+\infty$.