# Evaluating limits with complex numbers

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, limits

In lieu of my old question, I have a new question
[Old Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260550/show-the-integral-converges-to-these-value)

> Let $t > 0, a$ both real.
>
> What is $$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{(ai - t)x}$$

I am confused because we have an imaginary unit $i$ there, so how does it work?

Comment: What is $|e^{(ai-t)x}|$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, it is $1$, but what does absolute value have to do with the limit is my question

Comment: How did you get 1?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, sorry, is it $e^{-t}$?

Comment: Where did the $x$ go?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, can you tell me? I am really confused

Comment: Is $x$ real or complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write 
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} e^{(ai-t)x} = \lim_{x\to \infty} e^{aix}e^{-tx}  $$

The first term is oscillatory as you may rewrite in terms of sine and cosine functions. Their absolute value are bounded since $-1\le \sin(ax) \le +1$ and similarly for cosine function. Therefore this term is bounded for any value of $x$. The other term is an exponential function  that vanishes at infinity ($t>0$).

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} e^{aix}e^{-tx} = \lim_{x\to \infty} e^{aix} \lim_{x\to \infty} e^{-tx} = finite \times 0 = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a logarithmic spiral, with $\theta=ax$ and negative flair coefficient, $b--t/a$, and therefore will undoubtedly spiral to the origin as $x\to\infty$. Thus,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{(ai - t)x}=0$$